# Opened_tables value and tweaking table cache

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I've been reading on improving performance of my database, and ran into things called `table-open-cache` and `Opened_tables` . The MySQL doc told me the following:

> `Opened_tables`
>
> The number of tables that have been opened. If `Opened_tables` is big, your `table_open_cache` value is probably too small.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Opened_tables)

What do they mean by *big*? How much big is big enough to increase cache?
Okay, so I'm checking, how many tables are opened and seeing this:

```
 ---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Opened_tables | 711353 |
```

I'm increasing `table-open-cache` to 32768 (in fact, it was only 2000 before) and `opened_tables` is still growing.

An hour later, `opened_tables` is almost 750000.

And 20 hours later, it is 754000, so definitely the growth slowed down significantly, but still going.

Also, number of `Open tables` in `mysqladmin status` seems to have stopped increasing, or almost stopped. Well, it still increments by 1 every 5 minutes or so.

Currently `mysqladmin status` tells me this:

```
Opens: 754575  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 19725  Queries per second avg: 57.912
Opens: 754578  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 19725  Queries per second avg: 57.912
Opens: 754585  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 19725  Queries per second avg: 57.912
Opens: 754589  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 19725  Queries per second avg: 57.912
```

I've called it 4 times consecutively, so as you can see that `Open tables` is not growing, but `Opens` is growing.

How can it happen, if `Open tables` is still far away from `table_opened_cache` value which I set to 32768 about 21 hours ago?

Could you advice anything on tweaking this value and explain the results I got by this moment?

I have plenty of RAM for my purpose, and increasing table cache to 32k made server use 400MB more memory, but I still have 14GB free of 16.

What conclusions should I make at this point?

Comment: 'flush tables' closes all the tables and they have to be reopened. What does stopping the flush tables achieve?

Comment: @dan how do I do that? Do you mean that flushing occurs without my intervention?

Comment: @nicael         You could A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; for Beginning anchor list to be posted and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%flush%'; for Beginning flush list.  An hour later do the same A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; and post the AFTER 1 HOUR counts for us to see the activity counts and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS  LIKE '%flush%'; for the AFTER 1 HOUR flush counts.  And we will all see what is going on with this part of your server.  Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Wilson Thank you! I'll do it soon

Answer (score 1):

Dived `Opened_tables` by `Uptime` to get tables opened per second.  But even that is not very useful.

Much more useful are the 3 values of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'table_open_cache%';`  More than a few misses or overflows per second is worth noting.

There are many other metrics; provide the data that Wilson mentioned; see can dig further.

Only one `FLUSH TABLES` since boot up?  No big deal.

`mysqladmin status` does not provide much useful info.

Be aware that the values in `STATUS` have different flavors, has many flavors:

- Counters -- monotonically increasing since startup.  In most cases, dividing by Uptime is appropriate.  Eg: Opened_tables; Com_%.
- High-water-marks -- eg:  Max_used_connections
- Current values -- eg: Threads_running (usually 1, namely the query that is fetching the values)